# Instant communication of heavy body

Tags: quantum-mechanics

A transmitter projects a powerful photon beam which forms a (probability) cone. An instrument measures the direction of the force exerted by the transmitter.

When a large mass such as a black hole crosses the cone at a distance one million light years then for the perpendicular cross section suddenly most of the mass with the ability to interact with a photon is located in one small spot.

This should mean that most of the photons will interact with the large mass. This should mean that the direction of the force exerted by the transmitter a million years **earlier** will change.

This means that the motion of the large mass can be seen **before it happens** (speaking informally) but I thought that faster than light communication was impossible.

Comment: *"This should mean that the direction of the force exerted by the transmitter a million years earlier will change."* Why do you say that?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how it would happen. If you send out a beam of light, and 1,000,000 years later it interacted with something that could reflect some of the light back, then 1,000,000 years after that you could detect the reflected light. So 2,000,000 years after you sent the light out, you could detect the change, not instantly.

Comment: I am not referring to the reflected light.
The photon when emitted but before it interacts much later exists in all the possible paths which it could take.  This should mean that the force it exerts is in the direction pointed to by the cone.  When the photon interacts then the force should be in the direction of a vector from the interaction point to the emission point which is a different direction.
This difference should be detectable.

Comment: In your frame of reference, the photon travels at a finite speed, it does not instantly exist everywhere it could ever be.

Comment: Obviously the possible paths of the photon are in time and space (dimensions).
Your comment is not relevant to the question.

Comment: ok good luck with that.